# How to send the user directly to the review page on The App Store?

Tags: ios, ios6, app-store, review

Up to now (with iOS < 6.0), I used the following URL and code to send the user directly to the review page of my app (to rate it with 5 stars and post a  friendly comment :)):

```
NSString *stringUrl = @"http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=XXXXXXXX&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=1&type=Purple+Software&mt=8";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringUrl];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

This code doesn't work anymore when I run my app on a device with iOS 6 (and the new appstore of iOS 6). The appstore opens but then I have got an alert saying "Cannot connect to Appstore".

Anybody knows how to send the user directly to the review page of the Appstore on iOS 6 ? (note that I know how to send the user on the description of my app by this not what I want !)

Thanks !

Comment: iOS 6 material is under NDA and can not be discussed outside of Apple forums.

Comment: Same comment as those above; also I voted to close this as not constructive on the grounds that issues with beta software are likely to be temporary and in any case per the NDA we can't really support the question or answer with facts or references.

Comment: Guys, can we please not lie to him about [SO's commitment to the NDA](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137726/limits-of-ios-6-nda) He's free to ask, and we are free to answer him.

Comment: @CodaFi I do not see anybody lying. Nobody said that he was prohibited to ask by the rules of SO. I certainly know what you are up to and you are correct. Still your comment does not apply, I think.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use url like this

> `https://userpub.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZUserPublishing.woa/wa/addUserReview?type=Purple+Software&id=561892747&mt=8&o=i`

I found it on a link to "write a review" in Apple receipt email.

Comment: Well, I just tested it (Apr 2013) in both iOS5.1.1 and iOS6 and it works! Thanks Joyh

Comment: @Regis_AG No (beta4 AUG 2013)

Comment: @Regis_AG As of beta 6 this still doesn't work, not looking hopeful.

Comment: Here's how to do it in iOS 7 but it doesn't take you to the reviews tab it just takes you to the app page http://stackoverflow.com/a/18906304/1374512. I've also found that the `SKStoreProductViewController` class doesn't work properly for writing reviews because when using it, you can't actually tap the "Write a Review" button!

Answer (score 5):

I guess apple almost fixed the issue, since it can go to the review page directly with the same address  again.  Users still need to tap the button of review on iOS6 after they are directed to the review page though.

Comment: I tested this in February 2013, and it is still true! Awesome!

Comment: I confirm as well. Address in original question works fine. iOS 6.1.