# Rate and review within an app possible in iOS7?

Tags: ios, appirater

I have heard that iOS7 allows users to rate and review an app within that app, avoiding the need to redirect to appstore and leaving the app. So far, I have only found the difference in the URL links for the rate feature in itunes as mentioned in [ITunes review URL and iOS 7 (ask user to rate our app) AppStore show a blank page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905686/itunes-review-url-and-ios-7-ask-user-to-rate-our-app-appstore-show-a-blank-pag), but not how to stay inside the app.

I'm using Appirater in my app and integrated the new url and app goes to appstore for rate/review.

Can anybody tell me if this new feature is there and how to implement it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for the SKProductViewController.

You can present a SKProductViewController with the following code:

```
NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"YOURITUNESAPPID" forKey:SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier];

SKProductViewController *productViewController = [[SKProductViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:productViewController animated:YES completion:nil]];
```

This assumes that you're in a UIViewController subclass and know your iTunes application identifier. This will display a model viewController displaying the AppStore entry for that application.

Users are able leave ratings from that viewController. Haven't been able to write a review though.

Comment: This does not work, Apple has disabled the possibility to review apps using `SKProductViewController` in iOS 7.

Comment: You are not using the `parameters` variable in your example

Comment: @mattsson you're correct, I just unfortunately found out that the 'Write a Review' button isn't enabled. Would've been awesome if it was enabled :(

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue using Appirater, I have partially solved the proplem in this way

define the template for iOS7:

`NSString *templateReviewURLiOS7 = @"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/idAPP_ID";`

make this chnges on the rateApp method

```
+ (void)rateApp {

    .
    .
    .

// this URL Scheme should work in the iOS 6 App Store in addition to older stores
NSString *reviewURL = [templateReviewURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"APP_ID" withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _appId]];

   // iOS 7 needs a different templateReviewURL @see https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater/issues/131
   if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0) {
       reviewURL = [templateReviewURLiOS7 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"APP_ID" withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _appId]];
   }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

this will open the rate page in iOS6 as was in the past, and the app page in iOS7

Comment: I did this aswell, but this again takes me to appstore away from my app.