# Detect version of ios using libgdx with robovm backend

Tags: java, ios, libgdx, robovm

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18907231/554397) answer we need to know the version of ios. How can I achieve it using libgdx's robovm backend?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When running under RoboVM `java.lang.System.getProperty("os.version")` will return the iOS version.

Answer (score 2):

Easier to use, if you are in iOS module:

```
import org.robovm.apple.foundation.Foundation;

Foundation.getMajorSystemVersion()
// and
Foundation.getMinorSystemVersion()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.robovm.apple.foundation.FoundationVersionNumber;

if (FoundationVersionNumber.getVersion() < FoundationVersionNumber.Version_iOS_8_0)
```