# UIApplication openURL does not point to the correct destination in iOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, uiapplication

I have an application that after a button click sends the client to the AppStore in order to download an new app. This is done with the following code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/app/yyy-mobile/id4xxxxx89"]];
```

This line of code worked fine until iOS6, but after the latest v7 iOS SDK the code broke.

How do we resolve the issue? Do we need an if/else logic checking if the device has iOS 7 installed? For example:

```
if( iOS < 7 ) { // keep old logic 
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/app/yyy-mobile/id4xxxxx89"]]; } 
else // new logic for iOS 7  
     //TBD 
}
```

Or it would be better to replace the old line with new code that does the job for iOS7 and iOS6 (ie, a new method that is backwards compatible)?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18906304/1515075

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can recommend using the iOS 6+ SKStoreProductViewController as seen in the Appirater project: https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater/blob/master/Appirater.m#L485 (+rateApp)

It will show the app store window right inside your app, which is much faster than the old solution using -openURL

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want this solution. I want the AppStore to be opened  in a separate app

Comment: Have you tried the URL used in Appirater for iOS 7? 

NSString *templateReviewURLiOS7 = @"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/idAPP_ID";

Comment: I have tried it with iOS6 and it worked. If this works with iOS7 I will use this string, since I don't need an if/else snippet