# How to confirm if someone rated my iOS app?

Tags: ios

Is there a way to confirm programatically if someone rated/reviewed my app on the AppStore?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is doesn't meet SO's criteria so you added another sentence.

Comment: No, there isn't. The best you can do is [forward someone to the app store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905686/itunes-review-url-and-ios-7-ask-user-to-rate-our-app-appstore-show-a-blank-pag).

Comment: The error it displayed was vague so I assumed too short. My bad. I'll go read rules and pay closer attention next time.

Answer (score 3):

**The answer is simple. There is no way to check it**.

The only thing you can do is to open the `AppStore` app with a page of your application. However, if user rates your app there or not, remains unknown and you cannot know it.