# Link Directly to the "Write a Review" Page for an App in the App Store

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, app-store, itunes-app

Does anyone know how to link directly to the "Write a Review" page in the app store for iOS7 & iOS8?

Specifically, I want to go to the app review page and then automatically bring up the "Write a Review" screen (see below), making it easier for users of our app to write a review.

[image: App Store Screen Shots]

I've seen [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905686/itunes-review-url-and-ios-7-ask-user-to-rate-our-app-appstore-show-a-blank-pag) and [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124080/app-store-link-for-rate-review-this-app), which provide details on linking to the "review" section.

**My question is different – I want to also bring up the "Write a "Review" window as well.**

Is this possible?  If not, is there an alternative you might recommend?

Comment: i don't think this is possible, but it would be great if it was.

Comment: You can link to your app page, but not the "write a review" page.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is possible, using the link -> `itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id\(appID)&mt=8` with a get a parameter in the end : **`?action=write-review`**

```
let appReviewURL = "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id\(appID)?action=write-review&mt=8"
print(appReviewURL)
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:appReviewURL)!,options: [:])
```

This should launch the "Write a Review" page for the specified "appID".

Comment: Awesome!  Perfect answer, works great on iOS9+.  Thanks a million – I was about to give up on this one.

Comment: Works just perfect on iOS 11.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as has been seen [previously on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905686/itunes-review-url-and-ios-7-ask-user-to-rate-our-app-appstore-show-a-blank-pag), what you can instead do is link to the AppStore for your App and hope the user writes a review

You can construct the URL like this:

```
http://itunes.com/apps/<APP_NAME>
```

And open it like so:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:itunesURLString]];
```