# Open iTunes review page with a deep link from website

Tags: itunes, desktop-application, deep-linking, review

Open iTunes desktop (mac/windows) application review page with a link It's that possible?

`itmss://` I understand it is iTunes deep link to open the app from a browser. In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905686/itunes-review-url-and-ios-7-ask-user-to-rate-our-app-appstore-show-a-blank-pag), the URL given works, but shows an old page in which you can not write or see reviews. Can I make something similar?

[image: Write a rating on iTunes]